# How to export 3D graphic with animation as a "3ds" file

Tags: export, animation

I want to  export the following [Lorenz Attractor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorenzAttractor.html) as a "3ds" file (or "obj") 
  **with animation**

and import it into the [Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/)

```
sol[s_] := Transpose[Through[{x, y, z}["ValuesOnGrid"] /.First@NDSolve[
   {x'[t] == s (y[t] - x[t]), 
   y'[t] == 28 x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], 
   z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - 8 z[t]/3, x[0] == z[0] == 0, 
   y[0] == 2}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 25}]]]

 anim=Animate[Graphics3D[{Blue, Tube[sol[s]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {-30, 30}, {0, 50}}], {s, 1, 20, 0.01}, 
 AnimationRunning -> True, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

[image]

I tried :

```
Export["lorenz.3ds", anim]
```

but there is an error message :  *"Manipulate cannot be exported to the "3DS"* format."

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas!

Comment: As far as I know, 3DS is not meant for that. For a start you can export frames of the animation each into a singe 3DS file... What are you going to do with the result in the end?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm going to make a simple  AR app with unity, first of all  I want to press some button and run animation. I can export frames of the animation but I have no idea how to use each frames for my goal

Comment: Are you sure that Unity handles 3D animations with 3DS format?

Comment: Moreover, 3DS is really an antique format type. Better use OBJ or even some data that stores the data in compressed form.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.